# How do I enable or disable Ajax Deduping?

Tags: duplicate-contacts

A recent bug report mentions that it affects users only when Ajax deduping is enabled. How do I find this option to review it? Both Google and code grepping are failing me.

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/12550

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable/enable Ajax Deduping in Display preference.

Navigate to CiviCRM >> Administer >> Customize Data and Screens >> Display Preferences.

[image]

HTH

Pradeep